# How to solve SyntaxError: (unicode error) when opening a text file?

Tags: python

While trying to open a text file

```
f = open("testfile.txt", "r")
```

I am getting SyntaxError:(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
I have tried the code both in python 3.6 and 3.7 but did not work.
Please help me to fix this problem.

Ps. kindly avoid suggesting me this:

```
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Thank you.

Comment: The code you posted clearly did not produce that error.  Most likely, your actual code has a Windows pathname with backslashes, that Python is interpreting as escape sequences.  Either double the backslashes to escape them, use a raw string to remove their special meaning, or use forward slashes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the file path as

```
f= open(r"C:\Users\subra\Documents\testfile.txt")
```

as a raw string